# How to recreate the progress bar rotation?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

How can I recreate the rotation of a `ProgressBar` of type `progressBarStyleLarge`?

I have this layout:

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingIndicator"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loadingindicator"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />
```

Drawable `loadingindicator`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="40"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff00ff"
            android:centerColor="#ff00ff"
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

But this causes a smooth constant rotation instead of the - I believe - 2 parallel rotations that are displayed with the default style.

Specifically I want to recreate the animation of the `Indeterminate circular progress indicator`, as shown here:
https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/#circular-progress-indicators

XY question disclosure:
I need this because I want to customize the stroke thickness and outer margin of the ProgressBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CircularProgressDrawable` in code like:

```
val drawable = CircularProgressDrawable(context).apply {
    strokeWidth = // desired width in pixels
}
progressBar.indeterminateDrawable = drawable
```

Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CircularProgressDrawable

Comment: Also if you want to learn how to make the animation yourself, here's a shameless plug for a blog post on the subject that I wrote a couple years ago:
https://medium.com/@patrick_iv/simple-frame-by-frame-spinner-animation-b5065f26124f

Comment: Quick follow-up: how can I change the stroke color programmatically in that drawable?

Comment: If I remember correctly you can do it by calling `drawable.setColorSchemeColors(color)` with the color as ARGB value

Comment: You are correct! Side note: Setting multiple colors makes the drawable iterate through the colors, much like Google's multi-colored spinner animations.